# reset Interval after a specific command

Tags: javascript, discord, intervals

I have my code and I made it so every 5 seconds it sends a message (`Interval`) and now I want it to reset the timer on the Interval after either @bclear or @bfound is typed. (@) is a prefix. Here's my code

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}start`)) {
    message.delete()
    setInterval(function() {
      lastbuffer++;
      client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send('<@&700343773342990337>').then(msg => {
        msg.delete();
      })
      client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send(Buffer).then(msg => {
        msg.delete({
          timeout: 4000
        })
      });
    }, 5000)
  }


  if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}bclear`)) {
    message.delete()

    setInterval(5000);

    client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send(BufferClear);
    lastbuffer = 0;
  }
  if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}bfound`)) {

    message.delete()

    const BufferNClear = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#FF0000')
      .setTitle('Buffers are NOT clear!')
      .setDescription('Enemies are building a cannon on us!')
      .addField("Triggered By: ", message.author.toString(), true)
      .addField("Time triggered: ", datetime, true)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter('we got splitL')

    client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send("<@&700343773342990337> Stay alert! Enemies on our walls!")
    client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send("<@&700343773342990337> Stay alert! Enemies on our walls!")
    client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send("<@&700343773342990337> Stay alert! Enemies on our walls!")
    message.delete();
    client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send(BufferNClear)
    lastbuffer = 0;
  }

})
```

Comment: Start by saving the reference to the timeout: `let tId = setTimeout()...` then you can do `clearTimeout(tId)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval()` returns an intervalID that you should store in a variable. 
Later on, when you want to stop the interval you have to call 
`clearInterval(intervalID)`.
More details in [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

```
//just make sure it has access to the params it needs to work
function sendMessage() {
  lastbuffer++;
  client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send('<@&700343773342990337>').then(msg => {
    msg.delete();
  })
  client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send(Buffer).then(msg => {
    msg.delete({
      timeout: 4000
    })
  });
}

let intervalID;
const intervalSeconds = 5000;

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}start`)) {
    message.delete()
    intervalID = setInterval(sendMessage, intervalSeconds)
  }

  if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}bclear`)) {
    message.delete()

    clearInterval(intervalID);

    client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send(BufferClear);
    lastbuffer = 0;

    intervalID = setInterval(sendMessage, intervalSeconds)
  }
  if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}bfound`)) {

    message.delete()

    clearInterval(intervalID);

    const BufferNClear = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#FF0000')
      .setTitle('Buffers are NOT clear!')
      .setDescription('Enemies are building a cannon on us!')
      .addField("Triggered By: ", message.author.toString(), true)
      .addField("Time triggered: ", datetime, true)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter('we got splitL')

    client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send("<@&700343773342990337> Stay alert! Enemies on our walls!")
    client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send("<@&700343773342990337> Stay alert! Enemies on our walls!")
    client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send("<@&700343773342990337> Stay alert! Enemies on our walls!")
    message.delete();
    client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send(BufferNClear)
    lastbuffer = 0;

    intervalID = setInterval(sendMessage, intervalSeconds)
  }

})
```

Comment: everythings fine but i dont wanna stop it, I want to reset It so every time someone types @ bclear or @ bfound it counts 5seconds from that moment and then continue with the interval @d3bgger

Comment: there is no problem with that. You have to first stop the interval, and then re-create it. In order to do this, you have to keep the function outside of the interval (not declared inside the interval). Then you just call setInterval(sendMessage)

Comment: i updated my answer with a complete example of what i mean

Comment: thank you so much!!!! i did something similar to what you said and it worked perfectly